# Running Unix Shell script via batch file

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a unix shell script which I successfully run through Cygwin. As the script is to be used by someone with no IT knowledge I wanted it to be executed via batch file.

I created .bat file with the following content:

```
@echo off
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh
```

It fails to run though with the following errors:

```
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 9: ls: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 9: awk: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 10: date: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 15: cat: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 15: sed: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 15: uniq: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 99: rm: command not found
C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh: line 100: mv: command not found
```

I updated `PATH` to include `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash`.

Is there anything that I missed?

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest accessing the script with the path to the script in Linux form and so for example: C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe "/home/user/converttocsv.sh". Make sure that the script is seen as executable with Cygwin.

Comment: Path should include `c:\cygwin64\bin` rather than `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash`, I think.

Comment: `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l C:\Sparkpay\MainScripts\converttocsv.sh`